# I have an "address payable", not "address" error

Tags: solidity, addresses, payable

I have an error "TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"" on

```
function withdraw() payable public {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

in the line "msg.sender.transfer"

Answer (score 0):

address and payable address both store 160-bit length address, but If you want to send ethers to a particular address you need to specify them as payable address.

ways to define payable address:

address addr1;
address payable addr2 = payable(addr1);

or

address payable addr;
payable(addr).call("")...

As much I  know you need to specify payable two times. once while declaring and once while using.

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

this means that your type "address" (`msg.sender`) has no access to the send, transfer and call functions, it cannot send eth, in order to do so you need to use another type : `address payable`

*Documentation:*https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/types.html#address

> address payable: Same as address, but with the additional members transfer and send.

In order to do the latter you need to:

- use a type modifier : "`payable`" when you initialize the address variable *(you create a container for storing addresses that can pay and receive eth)*
- typecast the "msg.sender" address type during the declaration of the payable address variable *(you fill the container with an address).*

*Documentation:*

> conversions from address to address payable must be explicit via payable().

it will give you the following :

```
  address payable owner;
  owner = payable(msg.sender);
```

and from now you can use send and transfer.